# looking for a solution managing 1mb session data efficiently in asp .net

Tags: asp.net, iis, caching, session-state

This question is about performance in .net.
I have a project which shows 10,000 product information in a grid.

The .net project we have used HTML table to display information .At a time 500 records in a page is shown.And on click of the page numbers the relevant page information is shown.

Grid has actions ,delete ,group ,sort ,filter .
To achieve this we are currently bringing all 10,000 product information from DB(this subtotal result  is actually retrieved from 2 DB calls and 2 web service calls)  and keep them in session ,and later retrieving the page wise data from session.each page is brought by ajax call-and each ajax call pick up the relevant page data from session -resultset

Now this has a huge performance hit in production where session is maintained in SQL server,

I am looking for a solution managing this result object(1mb data per user) efficiently.
A call to service and db's to get each page data is again heavy.

Thanks
SNA

Comment: Does each user really have 10,000 independent products? It sounds like the sort of thing that ought to be shared between all users - so the session would be the wrong place to keep it.

Comment: No.. products vary upon each user.And the count is minimum 1000 to max 10000 per user.Each user is managing his product information he products he purchased online.I am not sure at a time how many users hit right now.we can now take it as 50 to 100.

Answer (score 3):

Do you really need to copy all 10,000 records from your database for every user? If these 10,000 are the more or less the same for every user, then you probably need to [cache the data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd861287.aspx) about products and store only the references to your cache (i.e. primary keys, memory addresses etc.)

What kind of information do you store in session apart from the product list? How many users do you have? Maybe you separate your data, using IIS [in-memory sessions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730855%28WS.10%29.aspx) for most critical and often requested data and the rest put to your SQL Server or just to use IIS in-memory sessions (if your server has enough capacity for it).

And finally, if that doesn't help, then you probably need to change your SLA and decrease the number of products stored in user sessions, rather re-querying them from database on demand. That is not optimal, but maybe 90% of your users won't notice anything.

Comment: No.. products vary upon each user.And the count is minimum 1000 to max 10000 per user.Each user is managing his product information he products he purchased online.I am not sure at a time how many users hit right now.we can now take it as 50 to 100. – SNA

Comment: Are you sure that it is session management and not the data fetching that constitutes your bottleneck? Anyway, the only way is then to use the in-memory sessions and you need to have a really good webserver with enough RAM to keep all these data in it.

Comment: Yes. we observed high traffic in session DB.Since we have to maintain this result set somewhere in server.. apart from session ,do you have any other suggestion ?. What do you think of keeping  this data somewhere in XML file saved in temp folder and each page request ,read the relevant data from file and destroy this file once session ends.(and other point is each page is brought by ajax calls each ajax call pick up the relevant page data from session -resultset)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me that you got these options:

1. There is really no need to send all products to the user. Using ajax makes it really easy handle a lot of items without having to push all to the user.
2. Store items client side. Cookies is not an option since they cannot store 1mb data. HTML5 got something called LocalStorage that you can use (but would then require that your users use a modern browser). Try LocalStorage here: http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/tests/storage.html
3. Store the table server side. i.e. Load everything into the Application storage and only store keys in each session. You could also use an external cache ([What are the advantages of Memcached compared to .NET Cache system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348273/what-are-the-advantages-of-memcached-compared-to-net-cache-system))

Comment: Session object is already located on the server side, so the reply is somewhat misguiding.

Comment: All three options are alternatives to storing the the session in files/database.

Comment: In my knowledge only the second point has something to do with it. AJAX (point 1) is just a way how you deliver data to client, the data has to be available somewhere on server -- here it is stored in the session. Point three potentially suggests an interesting thing like Memcached, but formulated in a bit too general way ("store your table server-side").

Comment: 1) No. Ajax enables you to move a lot more logic to the client side and by doing so minimize the need of page reloads and therefore not need to keep everything in a session. 3. Your question is generic, why would I go into detail for every alternative if I'm not sure if you want to use it? ***edit*** LOL. you are not even the one asking the question. Do some research before you comment other answers.

Comment: option2. using modern browser is not possible since this is a public web site and the current policy of the organization is that ,we cannot restrict the user's.Initially once we designed the application we had silverlight in mind ,so we can manage data at client side .But later we proceeded with asp .net.and performance is the issue.Now i need an efficient way to manage this 10,000 data with a reasonable performance.

Comment: Put all products in a cache like option #3, and only manage the keys in the `Session`. (Ids for all products that a user got access to). Should give you very good performance. Although I still don't understand why you cant use paged results instead of loading all products.